# VBA Creating an excel chart using values in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, charts

I have some data in a two dimensional array and I need to create a chart using excel charts. However, it seems that the charts setsourcedata accepts only range. This means that I have to store the array in a range on a spreadsheet somewhere and then pass the range to the chart as an input. So i created a temp sheet to store the data in a specific range and then plan to pass it to the create chart call. Here is a type that I created

```
Private Type CItem

CName As Variant
CWeek(13) As Variant
CDisabled(13) As Variant
CEmpty(13) As Variant
CEnabled(13) As Variant

End Type

Dim CItemArray(100) As CItem
cnt1 = 0

//.. do something

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("MainSheet")).Name = "WK_Report"

Worksheets("WK_Report").Range("C3:C15").value = CItemArray(cnt1).CWeek()
Worksheets("WK_Report").Range("D3:D15").value = CItemArray(cnt1).CDisabled()
Worksheets("WK_Report").Range("E3:E15").value = CItemArray(cnt1).CEnabled()
Worksheets("WK_Report").Range("F3:F15").value = CItemArray(cnt1).CEmpty()
```

My goal is to assign the entire array of CWeek for the first CItem to the range of C3:C15 respectively. However, the syntax  I used above assigns the first element of Cweek, CDisabled, CEnabled, CEmpty to the entire range. I tried without the parentheses after CWeek and others, but the result is same.

How can I assign the array values to the range? I know that the values are in the array because I did a debug.print after assigning to verify.

Comment: Try `Worksheets("WK_Report").Range("C3:C15").value = Application.Transpose(CItemArray(cnt1).CWeek)`

Comment: I tried this.. This reduces the output to a single item of the cweek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left out how you are populating the user defined type arrays but you should move to a 2-D variant array.

```
Private Type CItem
    CName As Variant
    CStuff(1 to 13, 1 to 4) As Variant
End Type

Dim CItemArray(100) As CItem, cnt1 as long

//.. populate 100 CItemArray.CStuff with 13 rows by 4 columns each

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("MainSheet")).Name = "WK_Report"

cnt1 = 1
with Worksheets("WK_Report").Range("C3")
    .resize(ubound(CItemArray(cnt1).CStuff, 1), ubound(CItemArray(cnt1).CStuff, 2)) = CItemArray(cnt1).CStuff
end with
```

From my point of view, the user defined type is only getting in the way but once you get it working it may be a 'set and forget' type of thing. I used a 1-based array so you didn't have to add 1 to the ubounds.

Comment: "From my point of view, the user defined type is only getting in the way but once you get it working it may be a 'set and forget' type of thing. I used a 1-based array so you didn't have to add 1 to the ubounds."  Can you please clarify this?

Comment: 1. You need a 2-D array to transfer values directly to the worksheet in row by columns. You used 4 1-D arrays. 2. It might be easier to populate the user defined structure but it isn't easier to get it back to the worksheet and you declined to offer how you were populating it in the first place so... I dunno. 3. If you have a zero-based array and use its ubound to resize the destination them you have to add 1 to the ubound cuz there is no range of cells on the worksheet that is zero rows by zero columns.

Comment: Super! Thanks for your help and suggestion on moving to the 2 D array.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use `Application.Transpose`: here's a simplified example

```
Option Explicit

Private Type CItem
    CWeek(13) As Variant
End Type

Sub Tester()

    Dim itm As CItem, x As Long

    For x = 1 To 14
        itm.CWeek(x - 1) = x
    Next x

    ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C15").Value = itm.CWeek '>> all "1"

    ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D15").Value = Application.Transpose(itm.CWeek) '>> 1 to 13

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this.. it did not work   Worksheets("WK_Report").Range("C3:C15").value = Application.Transpose(CItemArray(cnt1).CWeek) The only difference is I am trying to refer to a particular CItemarray

Comment: '*it did not work'* is neither a valid error code or an adequate description of the problem.

Comment: @jeeped unfortunately, enter = submit for the comment, I was trying to get to the new line.. I tried Alt + Enter as well. it did the same. I gave up.I just edited my comment.. I will learn how to enter on new line in a comment. Cool?

Comment: Works fine for me, so something else is going on with your code...  BTW you cannot use newlines in comments.

Comment: Yep! I ran your code and it works. I am probably doing something wrong here.. given that I am trying to access a specific element of the citem array

Comment: @jeeped it turned out that i had incorrectly assigned values to my array. I figured it out and changed it.  The Transpose solution worked.